# fatal error: 'linux/bio.h' file not found

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, clang

When I try to compile my eBPF program with bio.h included I get an error.
How come I can include other Linux headers, but not this specific one?

I compile using the following command

```
clang -O2 -target bpf -c src/bpf_program.c -Ikernel-src/tools/testing/selftests/bpf -Ikernel-src/tools/lib/bpf -o src/bpf_program.o
```

Program:

```
#include <asm/ptrace.h>
#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include "bpf_helpers.h"
#include <linux/bio.h>

SEC("kprobe/nvme_queue_rq")
int bpf_prog(struct pt_regs *ctx) {
    ..
}

char _license[] SEC("license") = "GPL";
```

and I get this error

```
src/bpf_program.c:4:10: fatal error: 'linux/bio.h' file not found
#include <linux/bio.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [Makefile:36: build] Error 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The header files you pull in come from /usr/include/linux (which gets installed from include/uapi in the kernel repo), when you compile a userspace program with #include <linux/something.h>.

he kernel space headers are deliberately different, to keep you from trying to access things which are not accessible from outside the kernel.

UPDATE:
I'm not an expert on bpf programs, but a quick reading indicates bpf samples are (or were at some point) compiled using the Linux Kernel's KConfig Makefile system. If you use the samples/bpf/Makefile as a template, you may be able to compile against more in-kernel headers. I'm not sure if that is intended.

Comment: Ah - and here `bio.h` is not present, which explains why I can't include it.